# Querying data in OpenTSDB

Tags: database, opentsdb

so playing around with OpenTSDB and after inserting data using put I was wondering what the easiest way to query this new data would be. I'm currently telnetting to the database that is on zookeeper and running the commands there. I've looked at the telnet and HTTP versions and haven't really gotten anywhere significantly. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to see the datapoints in the form of graphs using the standard UI provided by OpenTSDB. it is usually on `http://<virtual machine ip>:4242`

OR

you could make a client app and use HTTP api for querying datapoints.

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1. Create file sample.json

  ```
  [
      {
          "metric": "johan.test1",
          "timestamp": 1346846401,
          "value": 42.5,
          "tags": {
              "article_id": "00010012",
              "bucket_id": "AAAA2",
              "parent_bucket_id": "AAAA"
          }
      },
      {
          "metric": "johan.test1",
          "timestamp": 1346846401,
          "value": 42.5,
          "tags": {
              "article_id": "00010013",
              "bucket_id": "AAAA2",
              "parent_bucket_id": "AAAA"
          }
      },
      {
          "metric": "johan.test1",
          "timestamp": 1346846402,
          "value": 2.5,
          "tags": {
              "article_id": "00010012",
              "bucket_id": "AAAA2",
              "parent_bucket_id": "AAAA"
          }
      },
      {
          "metric": "johan.test1",
          "timestamp": 1346846402,
          "value": 3.5,
          "tags": {
              "article_id": "00010013",
              "bucket_id": "AAAA2",
              "parent_bucket_id": "AAAA"
          }
      },
      {
          "metric": "johan.test1",
          "timestamp": 1346846400,
          "value": 15.2,
          "tags": {
              "article_id": "00010011",
              "bucket_id": "AAAA1",
              "parent_bucket_id": "AAAA"
          }
      }
  ]
  ```
- Step 2: Post it and add to opentsdb

  ```
  curl -X POST -d @sample.json -H "Accept: Application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:4242/api/put
  ```
- Step 3: Evaluate results: Run the query

  ```
  http://localhost:4242/api/query?start=0&m=sum:rsl.test3.pv{bucket_id=*}
  ```

  Results:

  ```
  [
  {
      "metric":"johan.test1",
      "tags":
      {   
          "bucket_id":"AAAA1",
          "parent_bucket_id":"AAAA",
          "article_id":"00010011"
      },
      "aggregateTags":[],
      "dps":{"1346846400":15.199999809265137}
  },
  {
      "metric":"johan.test1",
      "tags":
      {
          "bucket_id":"AAAA2",
          "parent_bucket_id":"AAAA"
      },
      "aggregateTags":["article_id"],
      "dps":{"1346846401":85.0,"1346846402":6.0}
  }
  ]
  ```

That's it. Hope that works for you too.

cheers,

Johan

Comment: A note for those using curl: the braces need to be escaped and the string quoted curl "http://localhost:4242/api/query?start=0&m=sum:johan.test1\{bucket_id=*\}"